# a few questions from database normalization

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

I have a few questions (I'm a beginner in database design). I know that to be in 3NF, I need to be in `1NF`, then `2NF`; But to be in `4NF`, do I need to be in `3NF` or `BCNF`? Now to the 2nd question, I know the transitive rule `(A-->B, B --> C, which implies A --> C)`, but if I have for an example, `FD (CE --> ABD, BD --> E)` could I say that `CE --> ABDE`? since there are `BD` in `ABD` (which I believe makes it a trivial dependency in this case since there's an `E` on the left, and right hand side). Please let me know, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization is often taught as a process of decomposition: 1NF then 2NF then 3NF, etc. That step-by-step approach is essentially a pedagogical exercise, in much the same way that schoolchildren are (or used to be) taught long division; it aids an understanding of some basic concepts even though those individual steps aren't something you would be likely to do outside of a classroom. Understanding that it’s a learning exercise, you should realise that there’s actually more than one way to achieve the same end results. For example, you didn’t mention EKNF which logically comes “between” 3NF and BCNF but is frequently ignored. If 3NF, BCNF, 4NF are what you are learning about then the most logical progression would be in that order: BCNF after 3NF and before 4NF.

CE --> ABD implies CE --> ABDE because E on the right-hand side is a subset of the left-hand side. CE --> ABDE is not a trivial dependency because trivial means that the *whole* of the right-hand side must be a subset of the left-hand side.